# default project in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am lecturer in Armenian University. I teach “Programming in C++”. During my lecture I demonstrate and execute on the screen many C++ programs using Microsoft IDE (Visual C++). Many years I used Visual C++ 6.0. I executed programs just by double-clicking  .cpp file without creating project. Visual C++ 6.0 created default project automatically. It was very convenient. Now I use new version - Visual C++ 2008 Professional Edition which has not such possibility. It is not  convenient because I have to create project for each .cpp file.

My question:
Is there a version of modern Visual C++ which has this possibility? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you do not need to create new project for each .cpp file. You can keep all .cpp files in only one project. Or you can just remove old .cpp file from the current project and add new .cpp file in the same project. So no need to create project again and again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any modern versions of visual studio provide that feature but you could use [Premake](http://industriousone.com/premake) to generate your project

Grab it [here](http://industriousone.com/premake/download)

Create a file named ***premake4.lua*** containing following lines

```
solution "MyApplication"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

   -- A project defines one build target
   project "MyApplication"
      kind "ConsoleApp"
      language "C++"
      files { "**.h", "**.cpp" }

      configuration "Debug"
         defines { "DEBUG" }
         flags { "Symbols" }

      configuration "Release"
         defines { "NDEBUG" }
         flags { "Optimize" }
```

Copy ***premake4.lua*** inside your source's directory, let's say ***c:\lesson1***

Then execute following command line inside same directory

```
c:\lesson1> premake4 vs2008
```

It will generate a solution and a project containing every .cpp, .h file in ***c:\lesson1*** directory

I hope this helps, feel free to ask me for more details